# Path too long, but it's not?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` against a file share and I'm getting some "path too long" errors. But when I dig into it, some of them aren't.

I'm using `-ErrorVariable` to capture the error details into a variable called `$ErrLog`. Then, the following to log them to a CSV:

```
if ($ErrLog.Length -ne 0)
{
    $ErrLog | ForEach-Object {

        # Gather details of interest.
        $ErrTarget = $_.TargetObject
        $ErrReason = $_.CategoryInfo.Reason

        # Write data to custom PowerShell object.
        $ErrObject = New-Object PSObject
        $ErrObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Target Path' -Value $ErrTarget
        $ErrObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Error Reason' -Value $ErrReason

        # Add error to log variable.
        $ErrList += $ErrObject
    }
}

# Announce number of errors, and write to log as needed.
if ($ErrList.Length -eq 0)
{
    Write-Output "No errors encountered.`n"
}
else
{
    $ErrList | Export-CSV $LogErrors -NoTypeInformation
    $ErrorsCount = $ErrList.Length
    Write-Output "Logged $ErrorsCount errors.`n"
}
```

The above code appears to be working just fine, but the data I'm getting from it doesn't totally jive with the error details.

The error details on the console say that file names must be less than 260 characters and directory names must be less than 248. Makes enough sense. However, all of the paths being logged are directories and some of them are even shorter than 200 characters!

The longest I have in the log is 259 characters. That one, and others above 248 characters make sense. The shortest is 186 though, and there's plenty others shorter than 248.

Why am I getting these "path too long" errors on directories that aren't? Is there something the error data should be telling me that I'm just not capturing in the log?

Comment: Try setting `$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'` and `$VerbosePreference='Continue'`, then run the `Get-ChildItem` command again. It should stop on the first error and spew more information.

Comment: @Eris Is there any way I can just capture that data in the error logging functionality I'm using already - i.e.: just add another property to the log? I don't know for sure that the first error I hit will be one of the shorter paths. It would be good if I could just run through the whole thing and capture that verbose data for all of them so I can see the difference (if any).

Comment: If you set both to `Continue`, it will spew all the information, without stopping. However, without seeing the original script, I can't really say how to make all that info go to the same log location.

Comment: @Eris In theory, I just need to know what the names are for the useful extra properties I would be getting from Verbose. Then I can pull them from the error object and into the log, like I'm doing with the above script parts.

Comment: Looks like the accepted answer on http://superuser.com/questions/932847/path-too-long-when-deleting-from-powershell-on-remote-computer?rq=1 is what you need. Just replace `del` with `dir`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path too long when deleting from powershell on remote computer](https://superuser.com/questions/932847/path-too-long-when-deleting-from-powershell-on-remote-computer)

Comment: It would be interesting to know if you work backward by first determining which directories (and/or files) are longer than max length and then excluding them from your results. Do you still get the errors on directories shorter than 248?Can you try this and use it to exclude these directories?

$chk = Get-ChildItem C:\Your_Parent_Directory -Directory -Recurse
$Files | WHERE-Object {$_.FullName.Length -gt 247} | Select-Object @{N='Length';E={$_.FullName.Length}}, FullName | 
    Sort-Object -Descending Length